# Response 405 in python requests post method

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, httpresponse, python-requests-html

I am trying to login to a website using python requests but I am getting response 405 error.
I almost added all the necessary things to login. **I am able to login manually by entering email and password but unable to login with python requests**.

The given email and password is correct and csrf token is also correct. Can anyone help me to login to the website?
I found similar questions in stack overflow but none of them is working for me

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Login details
login_url = 'https://id.workable.com/oidc/i/Kefaqe8c2wvMA9ZThPceF'
email = 'mail'
password = 'password'

# Create a session
session = requests.Session()

# Send GET request to retrieve the login page
response = session.get(login_url)

# Check if the request was successful
if response.status_code == 200:
    # Parse the HTML content of the login page
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    # Find the CSRF token input field
    # print(soup.prettify())
    csrf_token_input = soup.find('input', {'name': 'csrf'})

    # Extract the CSRF token value
    print(csrf_token_input)
    csrf_token = csrf_token_input['value']
    print(csrf_token)

    # Login data with the CSRF token
    login_data = {
        'email': email,
        'password': password,
        'csrf_token': csrf_token
    }

    # Additional headers
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.109 Safari/537.36 CrKey/1.54.248666 Edg/114.0.0.0',
        'Referer': login_url  # Example referer header
        # Add any other required headers
    }

    # Send POST request to login
    response = session.post(login_url, data=login_data, headers=headers, allow_redirects=True)

    # Check if login was successful
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print("Login successful!")
    else:
        print("Login failed. Status code:", response.status_code)
        print("\nCOntent : ", response.content)
else:
    print("Failed to retrieve login page. Status code:", response.status_code)
```

Comment: If you log in with your browser while tracing network connections in the development tools window, what do you see? I think you'll find -- minimally -- that the form gets POST-ed to a different URL. You would need to parse the login page to retrieve the `action` attribute of the `form` element.

Comment: Yeah. I checked the network connections. I understood